# Vue 3 router-view transition right

Tags: vuejs3, css-transitions, transition, vue-transitions

I want to do
if the child route is open I want to give `class="user"` `margin-right:200px` and I want to use `transition` while doing this. I also want `transition` to be done when I turn off the router.

`This Is The Route I Have`

```js
[
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: () => import('../pages/User/User.vue'),
    name: 'user',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: () => import('../pages/User/UserNew.vue'),
        name: 'userNew',
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

`User.vue`

```html
<template>
        <div class="main">
                <div class="user">Hello JACK
                        <router-link :to="{ name: 'userNew'}">
                                <span>Add User</span>
                        </router-link>
                </div>
                <div class="Form">
                        <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
                                <transition name="route">
                                        <component :is="Component"/>
                                </transition>
                        </router-view>
                </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: "User"
}
</script>
```

`UserNew.vue`

```html
<template>
        <div class="">
                <button @click="this.$router.go(-1)">Close</button>
                <form action="">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email">
                </form>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: "UserNew"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, did you gave a read to that one? https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html You'll need to create some CSS variables for the transition to be effective. This can also be useful: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html

Comment: I looked, but since it is not possible for me to solve it, I opened a question here. please reply for your answers.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Some effort is required from your side (cannot see any CSS tries here). We're not supposed to code you the whole thing. Also, there is probably a question like yours on Stackoverflow already.

Comment: I couldn't solve the css side, if you can help as css

Comment: From my first comment, [some example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqFks1u2zAMx1+F0ynFYivdMKDw1GK77AXWQw+6KDadqJUlQaLdL/TdS8VN+okWMCSSFn+kqP+9+BtjPY0oGqFym2ykM+3xJoZE0GFvRkdwrz1AZ8gsjmYbICGNye89gLwN1w1QGnGOPJSNF/6UPHDZIRyiM4TFI7UeiYKHP62z7dWpFgUDp/Ct7FqcnYfNxiH8d7ZD+A7/TIdKzjmcD6DOk/HZkmWGNwMWQjlb9XyS8+deVISpsv0TnsNbdC4oGWeGfIZwQMmXHXqV6dYVs34GV+gJU2VashPOI6ADogHjHKzqnxnQZKzCSL93Y3iNcGgm/AJxkqEd17at1nhnMS2Olxz8VZaTJRwffYSdO+tTGJYf1aPwolYf0lCejM1y3YvFj1W8KVSAEE1r6baB1VyEn3A3BrEUdijSqAYT68scPMtmR9RPP7IWzV4VWrCuiq/FlijmRsrct0Vsl7kOaSPZqtPoyQ5YYx6qdQrXGRODteD+DwzJwYnvldB3mDB9xnxz9B13r0vx8AizgAaZ).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :S

Comment: "it doesn't work" is quite limited from a debugging standing point. Please be more explicit as of what: you tried, what is not working, what you wish to have.